# How to pass value from jsp to controller using jquery

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, controller

I want to know how can I pass the parameters from JSP to the controller.
    I am trying to send through ajax call but its going to error function

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" name="syncSubmit" value="synchronize" id="submitSync" >
```

**JSP:**

```
$("#submitSync").click(function() {
    var campaignId = [];
    var accountSe_Id = $ {
        accountSe_Id
    };
    var accountId = $ {
        accountId
    };
    $("#selectedCampaigns option").each(function() {
        campaignId.push({
            "campaignId": $(this).val()
        });
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/partial-synch.json",
        processData: true,
        data: {
            campaignId: JSON.stringify(campaignId),
            accountSe_Id: accountSe_Id,
            accountId: accountId
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Controller:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/partial-synch.json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseBody
        public Object[] partialSync(
               @RequestParam("campaignId") String campaignId,
               @RequestParam("accountSe_Id") long accountSe_Id,
               @RequestParam("accountId") long accountId) {
           Object[] resposneBody = new Object[1];
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you getting

Comment: You could check the error but I would guess you need to return a Response with a 200 status to enter the `success` function. PS : Webservice tutorial should help you

Comment: I see you are triggering your function off of a 'submit' button. is that button inside a form?  If so, that form may be getting submitted, and not your click function.